# Is it possible to set "global" parameters for a plugin with multiple functions?

Tags: plugin

I've written a plugin that connects to another service to then display its data within my EE site.

Certain parameters are necessary for each tag - primarily things like a key, username. Is there a way to declare these once rather than within each function's parameter array? I'm currently doing that, which works, but seems… like a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set them as class variables inside your plugin's `__construct` function.

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->my_api_key = 'foo';
    // OR
    $this->my_api_key = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('my_api_key');
}
```

Then inside your other functions, just look at `$this->my_api_key`.

**UPDATE**

You can also do a hybrid of my and Yuri's answer:

```
function __construct()
{
    if($my_api_key = ee()->config->item('my_addon_my_api_key'))
    {
        $this->my_api_key = $my_api_key;
    }

    if($my_api_key = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('my_api_key'))
    {
        $this->my_api_key = $my_api_key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. Is one solution considered a better practice than the other? I was going to move them to config vars to save time/code within the template tag.

Comment: Generally I don't like to *require* that add-on users add config values in oder for my add-on to work, though it's good to offer as an option. I'll edit my answer to include a hybrid approach.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Annnnd…more letters here so SE will let me say that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving the configuration values to EE config (set them using EE config editor). They will be available as global config values then and you can access them like this: `$this->EE->config->item('my_plugin_username)`